# No Output Coming In Simple C Program

Tags: c

I have been asked a very simple question in the book to write the output of the following program -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float i=1.1;
   while(i==1.1)
      {
         printf("%f\n",i);
         i=i-0.1;
      }
return 0;
}
```

Now I already read that I can use floating point numbers as loop counters but are not advisable which I learned. Now when I run this program inside the gcc, I get no output even though the logic is completely correct and according to which the value of I should be printed once. I tried printing the value of i and it gave me a result of 1.100000 . So I do not understand why the value is not being printed?

Comment: Oh it's this question again...

Comment: You *have* read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most C implementations, using IEEE-754 binary floating-point, what happens in your program is:

- The source text `1.1` is converted to a `double`. Since binary floating-point does not represent this value exactly, the result is the nearest representable value, 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625.
- The definition `float i=1.1;` converts the value to `float`. Since `float` has less precision than `double`, the result is 1.10000002384185791015625.

In the comparison `i==1.1`, the `float` 1.10000002384185791015625 is converted to `double` (which does not change its value) and compared to 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625. Since they are unequal, the result is false.

Comment: So you mean that, the 1.1 inside the WHILE gets converted into a 'DOUBLE' and then is compared with the initial definition of the variable i?

Comment: @PranavJituri: `1.1` is a `double` constant wherever it appears. In the definition `float i=1.1;`, the decimal numeral is converted to a `double`, just to produce the value of `1.1`. Then, because it is used to initialize a `float`, the value is converted to a `float`. Then, in the `while` loop, `1.1` again has its `double` value. This `double` value of `1.1` is converted to the value used to initialize the `float` object.

Comment: I am getting correct output when I am typecasting the value of 1.1 inside the WHILE loop which I understand as FLOAT is compared with FLOAT. But another question which rises in my mind is, does every decimal value like 0.2 or 1.22 etc are initialized as double or some values can be initialized by the compiler to be float as well? I mean is it possible that there are some real values which if put in this expression might produce the output?

Comment: @PranavJituri: An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If it is suffixed by `f` or `F`, it has type `float`. If it is suffixed by `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`. If the number is a multiple of a power of two (positive or negative powers, such as 1/8), and the multiplier is less than 2**24 in magnitude, and it is within the range of `float`, then it is representable as a `float`, so the conversion from `double` to `float` does not change the value. E.g., `34.125` is a `double` but does not change when converted to `float`, when IEEE-754 is being used.

Answer (score 5):

The quantity 11/10 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point, and it has different approximations as `double` and as `float`.

The constant `1.1` in the source code is the `double` approximation of 11/10. Since `i` is of type `float`, it ends up containing the `float` approximation of `1.1`.

Write `while (i==1.1f)` or declare `i` as `double` and your program will work.

Comment: @Aubin: Please do not spread the myth about `==` and floating point. The notion that there is any problem with `==` is incorrect. In fact, the `==` operation is one of the few floating-point operations that always returns an exactly correct result, unlike `+` or `sqrt`.

Comment: @Aubin I write programs that test equality of floating-point numbers all the time and I never have any trouble: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/09/25/The-problem-with-differential-testing-is-that-at-least-one-of-the-compilers-must-get-it-right http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2 http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/01/A-conversionless-conversion-function2 . Well, I had once, but it was a compiler bug, now fixed.

Comment: @Aubin: Good programmers might not use `==` with floating-point, but experts do.

Comment: @Aubin I find that I often need it, and I appreciate your gracious evaluation of my skills.

Answer (score 2):

**[Comparing floating point numbers:](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)**<sub>1</sub>

> Floating point math is not exact. Simple values like `0.2` cannot be precisely represented using binary floating point numbers, and the limited precision of floating point numbers means that slight changes in the order of operations can change the result. Different compilers and CPU architectures store temporary results at different precision, so results will differ depending on the details of your environment. If you do a calculation and then compare the results against some expected value it is highly unlikely that you will get exactly the result you intended.
>
> In other words, if you do a calculation and then do this comparison:
>
> ```
> if (result == expectedResult)
> ```
>
> then it is unlikely that the comparison will be true. If the comparison is true then it is probably unstable – tiny changes in the input values, compiler, or CPU may change the result and make the comparison be false.

In short:
`1.1` can't be represented exactly in binary floating pint number. This is like the decimal representation of `10/3` in decimal which is `3.333333333..........`

I would suggest you to Read the article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

---

<sub>1. For the experts who are encouraging beginner programmers to use `==` in floating point comparision</sub>

Comment: The initial post didn't have the second line with the link, so it looked more like a general comment.

Comment: And a link to a long difficult document without a specific reference to look up in it isn't very helpful either. Would you answer a C question by “You are a victim of undefined behavior. Read the C standard [link]”? It is not very good even with the link, is it?

Comment: The document referenced MUST be read. This answer is the best.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; I do not think for an enthusiastic and curious programmer it is that much long that one can't read this document.

Comment: And I really don't know, why people on earth do serial downvotes?

Comment: @haccks - Don't worry dude, will read every bit of it tomorrow as it is already 3am here -.-

Comment: @SteveL; One thing I forgot to tell you. Sometimes people downvote with their mindset to downvote. These people are always in hunt for your mistake and once find any mistake, that's it. They would not like to leave a comment as they are coward (I named these people **Ghost Soul**). You can see they hardly remove their downvotes after editing, showing their vile mentality.

Comment: You recommend a document of tens of pages of maths that “for an enthusiastic and curious programmer it is that much long that one can't read”, and then you seem to claim that `==` is an advanced technique that cannot be recommended to beginners. It is the opposite. It is very easy to understand what `==` does. One does not need the document that you refer to to explain what the OP's program does (indeed, that document is not about C, and the subtleties of C have more impact on the seemingly odd behavior than IEEE 754 floating-point).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (Read it, seriously!) explains why floating-point arithmetic is deterministic and natural. It does not provide arguments why floating-point should be treated as unfathomable magic, except perhaps indirectly if the formulas inside scare you, and perhaps you hope to scare the OP in fearing the magic too.

Answer (score 1):

It is because i is not quite exactly 1.1.

If you are going to test a floating point, you should do something along the lines of `while(i-1.1 < SOME_DELTA)` where delta is the threshold where equality is good enough.

Read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors

Comment: Please do not recommend that people compare floating-point numbers with a tolerance. This is an error-prone method not generally suitable for all applications.